# Initialize an array by converting from another array

Tags: c#, arrays, delegates

Is there a way to initialize an array of one type from an array of a different type, where I could possibly provide a delegate/predicate to convert each element?

```
class foo
{
  public foo(string s);
}

string[] strs = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
foo[] foos = {an array of new foos, created with each of my strs};
```

Obviously, I can just do a `for` loop, but given everything else C# can do, there must be a one-liner for this. Maybe something like:

```
foo[] foos = strs.ToArray<foo>(s => new foo(s));
```

Comment: `foo [] foos = { new foo(strs[0]), new foo(strs[1]), new foo(strs[2]) };`

Comment: `strs.Select(x=>new Foo(x)).ToArray()`

Comment: I suppose I should have specified, for `strs` of an arbitrary length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Select` extension method to project from `string` to `Foo`, like this:

```
Foo[] foos = strs.Select(x => new Foo(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: And now I realize I've actually done this before. I feel like maybe "Select" is the wrong name for this method, but I can't think of a better one, except maybe "Project". Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @RichardRobinson the name is arguable, actually in java a `Select` is called `map` i.e. "map from one type to another type". personally, I feel `Select` is the most suitable name, as that's exactly what we're doing.